# Replace whole words only including _ as word boundry

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas

**Question:** How to replace only whole words by counting `_` as word boundary?

I have a `DataFrame` containing arbitrary strings like this:

```
    column1  column2
0  My World  MyWorld
1   Worldly  My_World
```

I also have a dictionary containing words I like to replace:

```
dictionary = {"World": "Planet", "My": "Your"}
```

To only replace whole words I modify the `dictionary` like this:

```
dictionary = {r'\b{}\b'.format(k):v for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

Then I call the replace function:

```
dataframe.replace(to_replace=dictionary, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

The entire code for debugging is here:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'column1': ['Hello World', 'Worldly'],
        'column2': ['myWorld', 'My_World_']
       }

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)

dictionary = {"World": "Planet", "My": "Your"}
dictionary = {r'\b{}\b'.format(k):v for k, v in dictionary.items()}

dataframe.replace(to_replace=dictionary, regex=True, inplace=True)

print(dataframe)
```

The result looks like this:

```
       column1   column2
0  Your Planet   myWorld
1      Worldly  My_World
```

**Problem:** The string `My_World` should be replaced by `Your_Planet`.

**Non Working Solution:** Adding `_` to the RegEx like this:

```
dictionary = {r'(\b|_){}(\b|_)'.format(k):v for k, v in dictionary.items()}
```

Then the words get found correctly, by the `_` gets replaced in the process:

```
       column1   column2
0  Your Planet   myWorld
1      Worldly  MyPlanet
```

Comment: Does something like this work? `dictionary = {r'(\b|_){}(\b|_)'.format(k):'\\1{}\\2'.format(v) for k, v in dictionary.items()}`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `_` along to `\b` with back reference:

```
df.replace({r'(\b|_)({})(\b|_)'.format(k): r'\1{}\3'.format(v) 
            for k, v in dictionary.items()},
           regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
       column1      column2
0  Your Planet      MyWorld
1      Worldly  Your_Planet
```